Cloudflare Turnstile Challenge Failed
In my implemetions of Cloudflare's Turnstile challenge via marsidev/react-turnstile, I have encountered a peculiar issue where, in invisible widget mode, occasionally the challenge fails and initiates repeated retries (retry is auto by default). Even with the retry option set to auto, the challenge failed issue persist for 20 or more attempts before finally resolving successfully.
I would like to understand:

What could be causing this behavior? Am I overlooking something
in my implementation?

If this behavior is indeed unusual, how can
I mitigate or prevent it from occurring?


P.S: I render the turnstile on a form button click.
          <Turnstile
            ref={turnstileRef}
            options={{ language: lang}}
            siteKey={siteKey}
            scriptOptions={scriptOptions}
            onError={() => {
                console.log("failing challenge");
                console.log("is token expired", turnstileRef.current?.isExpired())
            }}
            onExpire={() => {
                setStatus('token Expired');
            }}

            // Callback invoked upon success of the challenge. The callback is passed a token that can be validated.
            onSuccess={token => {
                console.log("Token ", token);
                setToken(token);
                setStatus('solved')
            }}
        />

Challenge failed in dev tools


If your browser console is open and you're emulating a mobile device, it can lead to the challenge failling.
If you still want to test how it looks on a mobile device, you can manually set the screen size and this should not interfer with the challenge.

it's not mobile device, I think the Cloudflare team needs to devise a clear solution since many users are encountering this problem.
